# Datatables.net Requested unknown parameter 'ImageUrl' for row 0, column 0

Tags: jquery, datatables

I've been trying to add a datatable to my site using JQuery and Datatables.net.
I've tried many solutions from stackoverflow and from Datatables.net but cant figure it out.
The odd thing is that it does load in the Json data as the number of entries shown in the footer of the table is correct. Any pointers on what the issue may be?

[image]

**This is the Json that is returned from my method as far as I can tell this is vaild Json**

```
{"data":[{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":20,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/2184_64.png","blueprintName":"Hammerhead I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":23581.52},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":20,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1145_64.png","blueprintName":"Antimatter Charge M Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":3598.87},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/2445_64.png","blueprintName":"Ogre I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":21757.32},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/2477_64.png","blueprintName":"Berserker I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":38405.71},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/2194_64.png","blueprintName":"Praetor I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":61750.2},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1214_64.png","blueprintName":"Wasp I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":40214.46},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/811_64.png","blueprintName":"Scourge Light Missile Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":560.32},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/812_64.png","blueprintName":"Inferno Light Missile Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":549.0},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1130_64.png","blueprintName":"Iron Charge S Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":205.5},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/814_64.png","blueprintName":"Nova Light Missile Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":540.46},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/810_64.png","blueprintName":"Scourge Heavy Missile Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":4126.82},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1134_64.png","blueprintName":"Thorium Charge S Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":555.91},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/901_64.png","blueprintName":"Phased Plasma L Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":10641.8},{"materialEfficiency":0,"timeEfficiency":0,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1140_64.png","blueprintName":"Iridium Charge M Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":1353.82},{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":20,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/1145_64.png","blueprintName":"Antimatter Charge M Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":3598.87}]}
```

**This is my JQuery**

```
$(function () {

$('.js-exportable').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
        "url": "Manufacturing/LoadData",
        "data": ""
    },

    "columns": [
        { "data": "ImageUrl" },
        { "data": "MaterialEfficiency" },
        { "data": "TimeEfficiency" },
        { "data": "BlueprintName" },
        { "data": "Location" },
        { "data": "ManufactureCost" }
    ]
});
```

});

**and this how I have created the table in the view**

```
<div class="row clearfix" style="margin-top:20px;">              
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Blueprints<small>Current blueprints owned by character</small></h2>
            <ul class="header-dropdown dropdown">
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="full-screen"><i class="icon-frame"></i></a></li>                    
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover dataTable js-exportable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Image</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                            <th>Material Efficiency</th>
                            <th>Time Efficiency</th>
                            <th>Estimated Manufacture Cost</th>                               
                        </tr>
                    </thead> 
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend. As you see the data response:

```
{"materialEfficiency":10,"timeEfficiency":20,"imageUrl":"https://imageserver.eveonline.com/Type/2184_64.png","blueprintName":"Hammerhead I Blueprint","location":"Sobaseki X - Moon 12 - Propel Dynamics Factory","manufactureCost":23581.52}
```

But you defined the columns like this:

```
"columns": [
        { "data": "ImageUrl" },
        { "data": "MaterialEfficiency" },
        { "data": "TimeEfficiency" },
        { "data": "BlueprintName" },
        { "data": "Location" },
        { "data": "ManufactureCost" }
    ]
```

So you need to return objects with the names that match your Datatables config like the following:

```
"columns": [
                        { "data": "imageUrl" },
                        { "data": "materialEfficiency" },
                        { "data": "timeEfficiency" },
                        { "data": "blueprintName" },
                        { "data": "location" },
                        { "data": "manufactureCost" }
                    ]
```

You can see the result here:
[image]

Hope to help, my friend :))

Comment: Gosh! Thanks Tomato32, dont know how I managed to miss the parameters where case sensitive.

Comment: @GreyWalker: Well played, my friend :d